# .net core gRPC client failed call server in the same azure linux vm

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, ssl, grpc

I am creating a simple gRPC server/client, but once I deploy both server/client on the Azure Linux VM(Ubuntu), I get the following error from client application

> rpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="Error starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.", DebugException="System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
> ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

I know from microsoft docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/core/grpc/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-3.1#call-a-grpc-service-with-an-untrustedinvalid-certificate) it is possible to ignore the error, but is there a way to trust the certification correctly?

**Part of my server appsettings.json**

```
"Kestrel": {
  "EndpointDefaults": {
    "Protocols": "Http2"
  },
  "Endpoints": {
    "HttpsInlineCertFile": {
      "Url": "https://localhost:5002",
      "Certificate": {
        "Path": "../Cert/localhost.pfx",
        "Password": "localhost"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Part of my server Program.cs**

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
            {
                logging.ClearProviders();
                logging.AddConsole();
                logging.AddNLog();
                // will be overwritten by settings.json
                logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

I have checked online, this incidicates that a certificate is not trusted.

**How I generate the certificate on my windows dev machine and copied to azure vm**

```
makecert -sv localhost.pvk -n "CN=localhost" localhost.cer -r
pvk2pfx -pvk localhost.pvk -spc localhost.cer -pfx localhost.pfx -po <password>
```

**Convert pfx to crt on azure linux vm**

```
openssl pkcs12 -in localhost.pfx -nodes -out localhost.pem
openssl rsa -in localhost.pem -out localhost.key
openssl x509 -in localhost.pem -out localhost.crt
```

**trust certificate with certutil**

```
sudo apt install libnss3-tools
# Initialize
mkdir -p $HOME/.pki/nssdb
certutil -d $HOME/.pki/nssdb -N
# Trust the certificate for SSL 
pk12util -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -i localhost.pfx
# Trust a self-signed server certificate
# I also tried -t "C,," here
certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -A -t "P,," -n 'local cert' -i localhost.crt

# I also tried below commands to trust the certificate
sudo cp local.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

and the same exception keeps poping up, am I missing anything? how can I trust my certification

Comment: You may be using TLS 1.0 or TLS 1.1 which has been obsoleted by many server recently.  You need to use TLS 1.2.  Make sure you are using latest gRPC.  You are using http/s which also requires TLS 1.2 (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2).

Comment: @jdweng I am using the latest gRPC template in VS and I believe it uses the latest gRPC nuget packages

Comment: Is certificate signed?  Your link has link to handle unsigned certificates.  Also make sure you have latest Core 3.1 with all patches.  It looks like error is due to the certificate and not TLS 1.2.  Read "TLS handshake" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security)  Check ClientHello with sniffer to verify TLS version.  I suspect you are using TLS 1.3 which doesn't support RSA.  So you either have to force TLS 1.2 or change encryption method in building certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I create a post [here](https://mp.weixin.qq.com/s/F-lrqZJtZZDYxrgQ7uETRg) explain how to create a certificate that will pass the validation.